# Unable to implement AVPictureInPictureController - tvOS 14.0+

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, apple-tv, picture-in-picture

When implementing PIP in tvOS 14.0+,
AVPictureInPictureController.isPictureInPictureSupported() returns as true

but, isPictureInPicturePossible returns as false.

Please help in understanding how to debug and implement pip in tvOS, we are using a custom avPlayer.

Capabilities are already set,

[image]

Also, the audio session is set up as follows,

[image]